# Subdataframes of Subdataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

If I have a dataframe df_i and I want to split it into sub-dataframes based on unique values of 'Cycle Number'

I use:

```
dfs = {k: df_i[df_i['Cycle Number'] == k] for k in df_i['Cycle Number'].unique()}
```

Assuming the 'Cycle Number' ranges from 1 to 50 and in each cycle, I have steps ranging from 1 to 15, how do I split each data frame into 15 further data frames?

I am presuming something of this type would work:

```
for i in range(1,51):
    dsfs = {k: dfs[i][dfs[i]['Step Number'] == k] for k in dfs[i]['Step Number'].unique()}
```

But, this will return me 15 data frames only from the cycle number corresponding to 50, not the ones before.

If I want to access a sub-dataframe in the 20th Cycle with step number 10, is there a way of generating the subdata frame such that I can access it using something like `dfs[20][10]`?

A simple parallel:

```
Step Number Cycle Number    Desired Access
1   1   dfs[1][1]
2   1   dfs[1][2]
3   1   dfs[1][3]
4   1   dfs[1][4]
5   1   dfs[1][5]
1   2   dfs[2][1]
2   2   dfs[2][2]
3   2   dfs[2][3]
4   2   dfs[2][4]
5   2   dfs[2][5]
1   3   dfs[3][1]
2   3   dfs[3][2]
3   3   dfs[3][3]
4   3   dfs[3][4]
5   3   dfs[3][5]
1   4   dfs[4][1]
2   4   dfs[4][2]
3   4   dfs[4][3]
4   4   dfs[4][4]
5   4   dfs[4][5]
```

Comment: please post your dataframe and expected dataframe

Comment: I put up a parallel, hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tuple keys instead and utilize `groupby`. Here's a minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 3, 7]],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])))

for k, v in dfs.items():
    print(k)
    print(v)

(0, 1)
   col1  col2  col3
0     0     1     2
1     0     1     3
(1, 2)
   col1  col2  col3
2     1     2     4
3     1     2     5
(1, 3)
   col1  col2  col3
4     1     3     6
5     1     3     7
```